# How to set `value` attribute to a button element

Tags: javascript, html

My html code where i store id :

```
<div class="image-id-holder">
    <button value=imageID>
    <input type="text" value=imageId />
</div>
```

html code where i am getting id, **$id** coming from while function from php script

```
<a href=\"#edit\" data-toggle=\"modal\">
   <button class=\"btn btn-primary image-id-btn\" data-image=$id>edit
   </button>
</a>
```

I have javascript code :

```
script>
      $(function(){
       $(".image-id-btn").on("click", function(){
            var imageId = $(this).attr("data-image");
            alert(imageId);
            $(".image-id-holder").children("input").val(imageId);
            });
        });    
</script>
```

i want to put variable imageId into button value property cause i want to store in button-value property instead of input property.

when i change children it's not work

```
$(".image-id-holder").children("button").val(imageId);
```

I am assigning this way :

```
<button value=imageId>
```

Whole idea is to fill all the fields on form for editing, so user doesn't have to rewrite all the fields on a form.

Comment: Could you please explain a little more clearly? So you have an input textbox and a button, when the button is clicked what do you need to happen? Also did i miss any other controls or inputs?

Comment: added my div-html code and the problem is:
value from button does not accept imageId value when children is change to it

Comment: @dongou Is this what your requirement is : http://jsfiddle.net/chpvr3k0/

Comment: Where is the `.image-id-btn` element that you bind the click on? And where's the closing `</button>` tag?

Comment: "Its not work" is not a valid question.

Comment: children('input') works fine but ...
children('button') does not work

Comment: ___What___ does not work? What is currently happening that is different from your expectation?

Comment: helped a lot :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yb3c-HljFro 
i will post solution later

Answer (score 0):

Try using `attr` or `prop`:

```
$(".image-id-holder").children("button").attr('value', imageId);
```

or

```
$(".image-id-holder").children("button").prop('value', imageId);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just simplifying the question and showing you the way to change the value of button on another button click

```js
   $(document).ready(function() {
         $(".image-id-btn").on("click", function(){
            var imageId = $(this).attr("data-image");
            alert(imageId);
         
           $(".image-id-holder").children("button").attr("value",imageId);
         
            $(".image-id-holder").children().children("input").attr("value",imageId)
            alert( $(".image-id-holder").children("button").attr("value"));
           
  });
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-id-holder">
    <button value="imageID">
    <input type="text" value="imageId"/>
</div>
  
<a href="#edit" data-toggle="modal">
   <button class="image-id-btn" data-image="changevalue">edit
   </button>
</a>
```